# Bind Unrelated property to DataGrid

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

**EDIT: Solved
(I made another property in the `ViewModel wrapper` and bound to that)**

I am trying to bind a property that is not related to the `ObservableCollection` that the `DataGrid` is bound to. The other columns are binding the way they should, it is just this one column that I can't seem to get to work.

I tried binding the property using `RelativeSource AncestorType` and directly to the `DataContext` with no luck.

The XAML, The `ObservableCollection` I am binding to obviously is called `MonthlyRecords` which is a collection of a different class and this is binding the way it should be. It is the `property` `SelectedTenant.FullName` which has nothing to do with the collection that is giving me grief.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MonthlyRecords}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <!--Trying to bind this Property in the next line-->
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SelectedTenant.FullName}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            <DataGridTextColumn Width="60" Header="Code" Binding="{Binding UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, Path=TenantCode}" />
```

This is the class for the property I am trying to bind.

```
public class Tenant 
{
    public Tenant()
    {
    }

    public int Code { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }        
    public string FirstName { get; set; }        
    public string FullName => LastName + " " + FirstName;
    public string Section { get; set; }

    public Tenant(int code, string lastName = null, string firstName = null,  string section = null)
    {
        Code = code;
        LastName = lastName;            
        FirstName = firstName;            
        Section = section;
    }
}
```

And this is the `property` in the ViewModel I am trying to bind to.

```
private Tenant _selectedTenant;

public Tenant SelectedTenant
{
    get { return _selectedTenant; }
    set
    {
        if (Equals(_selectedTenant, value)) return;
        _selectedTenant = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

What else do I need to do to get this to bind to the `DataGrid`?

Comment: is MonthlyRecords are the collection of Tenant? is that so why can't you directly bind FullName property in grid columns rather Name?

Comment: @SushilMate, `MonthlyRecords` is a collection of completely different class than `Tenant`. Hence the reason why I am having trouble.

Comment: How you binding SelectedTenant in xaml? if you show that code as well

Comment: @SushilMate, are you sure you are not reading another question? It is all there. I have the XAML I am using to try to bind the property in the question. I even put a comment in there to show where I was binding it

Comment: I mean to say are you binding SelectedTenant in xaml apart from datagrid, i have got it working through relative source have a look.

Comment: @SushilMate, yes I am binding it to a `ComboBox` in the same view.

Answer (score 1):

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedTenant.FullName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
```

Edit:

I have set AutoGenerateColumns="True"

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MonthlyRecords}" AutoGenerateColumns="True">

<DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding ElementName=ComboBoxTenant, Path=DisplayMemberPath}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I tried that and it does not work. Sorry.

Comment: strange try updated one, in my code i didn't try through vm though.

Comment: No, that does not help any either. Anyway, I figured it out. I made another property in the `ViewModel wrapper` and bound to that.

Comment: Okay, Another way to bind through ComboBox element DisplayMemeberPath. in that way, you don't have to create a new property in the VM.